# Dynamic Programming - Largest arrangement of bookcases

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve a problem, so I'm not looking for code, but for similar algorithms so I can solve it myself.

I am given `n` bookcases each with a `size` amount of books inside. I am to move SOME of these bookcases to a new room as follows:

- The first bookcase will always be moved;
- I will keep the order of the bookcases in the new room (I can't change positions in the new room, once I selected bookcase `6`, I can't select any of the book from `0 to 5`);
- Bookcase `i` cannot be placed next to either of the bookcases `i-1` or `i+1` (ex: I can't place ?-4-5-?/?-5-6-?/?-4-5-6-?);

Which configuration of bookcases will offer me the largest amount of books?

I understand that this is solved using a dynamic programming algorithm, but I am not sure which one. I initially thought it would be similar to the knapsack problem, but I don't have a limit of books so it's clearly different (at least I think it is).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Xzenon. Progammers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com or CS: http://cs.stackexchange.com might be a better bet to get Algorithms ideas.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this problem is underspecified.  The only constraint is that you can't put certain bookcases next to each other?  Do you have some sample data?

Comment: I think there is no need using dynamic programming...please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Make an array `int M[n]`, and set `M[0] = b[0]` because the first bookcase is always moved. Then proceed as follows:

- For each element `b[i]`, where `i > 0`, set `M[i] = b[i]`
- walk back through elements of `M` at indexes `j` ranging from `0` to `i-2`, inclusive; start at `i-2` because you cannot take the bookcase that precedes `b[i]`
- Set `M[i]` to the max of current `M[i]` and `M[j] + b[i]`. The meaning of this expression is "I take `b[i]` and attach it to the series of bookcases ending at `j`"
- Once the loop is over, walk through `M[]`, and find the highest element. This is your answer.
- To print the sequence of bookcase indexes start at the position of max element of `M[]` (say, `p`) and print `p`
- Now look back through `M` for a position `k < p` such that `M[k] = M[p] - b[p]`. There will be at least one such element because of the way the array `M[]` is constructed.
- Print `k`, set `p=k`, and continue until you get to the beginning of the array.